# How does Apple separate gravity from device acceleration in iPhone using accelerometer and gyroscope?

Tags: accelerometer, gravity, gyroscope, devicemotion

I know by combining accelerometer and gyroscope, we can access the gravity and device motion separately. But I need to know how does Xcode calculate it when I simply using `devicemotion.gravity`. Any algorithm available?